# Expression denotes a `method group', where a `variable', `value' or `type' was expected

Tags: c#, zip

I have a project which stores files from Unity project. What I want is to locate those files and to zip them. I want to use [ZipFile Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx). My code is very simple is the following:

```
string dataSource = @"D:\\dt\\2015-11-09-11\\";
string zipFile = @"D:\\dt\\2015-11-09-11\\file.zip";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dataSource, zipFile, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
```

However I am getting the error from unity:

> Assets/file.cs(54,25): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `method group', where a`variable', `value' or`type' was expected

What I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Ths issue was that ZipFile class is for .NET 4.5 and higher while unity is for .NET 3.5. I change the library I used as suggested in the commnets  the following [lib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Code-Reference). My code now is the following:

```
string dataSource = @"D:\\data\\2015-11-09-11-11-37-3286";
FileStream fsOut = File.Create(dataSource);
ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(fsOut);
zipStream.SetLevel(3);
int folderOffset = dataSource.Length + (dataSource.EndsWith("\\") ? 0 : 1);
CompressFolder(dataSource, zipStream, folderOffset);        
zipStream.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes the Close also Close the underlying stream
zipStream.Close();
```

CompressFolder method could be find [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples). I am receiving the following message (the dir is an existing path):

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "D:\data\2015-11-09-11-11-37-3286".
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor

The problem is located in the second line of the suggested code `FileStream out = File.Create(dataSource);`

Comment: `ZipFile` is available from .NET 4.5 onwards... Unity is way behind that, as far as I'm aware. Now quite why you're getting that *exact* error message is hard to tell without more context. My guess is that you have a method called `ZipFile` as well. It would be nice to know exactly what's at line 54, column 25 of file.cs...

Comment: Yes you are right is the third line CreateFromDirectory. I think that the case is the .NET confliction since unity support only 3.5. Any alternative to ZipFile for UNity?

Comment: You might want to use SharpZipLib instead.

Comment: Any idea how I can use that lib? I have donwload and store the dll to Assets in UNity project. Do you know any tutorial on how can I use that dll?

Comment: A search for "SharpZipLib tutorial" gets lots of hits, and there are lots of samples: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Code-Reference

Comment: I used the proposed implementation of the lib and I got the following error: DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path System.IO.FileSteam..ctor

Comment: Well that suggests that you gave it a path that didn't exist. An SO comment thread is not the way to resolve that issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out on a limb, I suggest that you have called a method `ZipFile` as well.

Rename it to something that doesn't clash with the class name or use a `Using alias = ...` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Unity has issue with browsing to unknown directories. When I change the dir to a folder tha Unity has access everything worked fine.